# Setting the vim color theme for highlighted braces

Tags: python, vim

How do you change the vim color scheme for highlighted braces? I'm looking to actually edit the .vim theme file to make the change permanent.

Regards,
Craig

Comment: This question is very close to needing transfer to SuperUser.com

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: programming editor questions belong on SO. (vim: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su emacs: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25785/where-do-emacs-customization-questions-belong-so-or-su-why/25787#25787 and so on). This is definitely a programming editor question - even if you love vim enough to write an essay in it, you're not going to be worried about counting matching delimiters. That's a programming task.

Comment: a question tagged with "python" with the word "braces" in it... Weird...

Answer (score 14):

The automatic highlight colour for matching brackets is called `MatchParen`. You can change the colour in your .vimrc by doing eg:

```
highlight MatchParen cterm=bold ctermfg=cyan
```

Comment: You can also add a ctermbg=black if you have a black background.

Answer (score 3):

After reading [the FAQ](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html), I can answer my own question. :)

> 24.9. Is there a built-in function to syntax-highlight the corresponding
>         matching bracket?
>
> No. Vim doesn't support syntax-highlighting matching brackets. You can try
>   using the plugin developed by Charles Campbell:
>
> http://vim.sourceforge.net/tips/tip.php?tip_id=177
>
> You can jump to a matching bracket using the '%' key. You can set the
>   'showmatch' option to temporarily jump to a matching bracket when in insert
>   mode.