# How to parenthesis hight colour when curser in one of them in Vim?

Tags: vim

Does anyone experience this that when you place curser in one of parenthesis pair(bracket braces also), vim hight light both of them in the relatively same colour. Many times I've had a hard time ti figure out which one is the one that my curser current place on, even the there is a blinking indication, but still hard to tell?

Any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: is this what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709064/setting-the-vim-color-theme-for-highlighted-braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:NoMatchParen
```

^ from the help in... :h matchparen

that place also tells you how to disable it by putting this thing in your vimrc, wowowow

```
let loaded_matchparen = 1
```